# Validation for route parameters in Laravel 6.x

Tags: validation, laravel-6

I'm using Laravel 6 and I want to use validators to validate my route parameters before using them in database queries.

**Route**

```php
Route::put('Brands/update/name/{id}', 'BrandsController@updatename')
    ->name('BrandUpdateName');
```

**Controller**

```php
public function updatename(Request $request, Brands $brands)
{
    $validatedata = $request->validate([
        'id' => ['required', 'numeric', 'exists:brands'],
        'BrandNameedit' => [
            'required', 'max:100', 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9 آابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهیئ\s]+$/', 'unique:brands,name'
        ],
    ]);

    try {
        $brands = $brands->find($request->id);
        $brands->name = $request->BrandNameedit;
        $brands->save();

        return $brands;
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        return ('error');
    }
}
```

I want to validate the id parameter before using it in `find($request->id)` but Laravel doesn't apply validations on route parameters. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. If you're using Route model binding, `Brands $brands` should validate that automatically by finding a record in your database or throwing an automatic 404 if it can't find one. Also, I don't think `$request->id` will contain anything; `$request->{value}` is used for accessing query params or post request input values.

Comment: and what about sql injection ?

Comment: You don't have to worry about SQL injection if you're using Laravel. Everything is internally sanitized when using Eloquent. You only really need to be aware of query input when using a `DB::raw('...')` statement.